# Failover clustering validation report error: Validate Active Directory Configuration

Tags: windows, cluster, clustering

I am deploying failover clustering on windows server 2012 r2 enterprise

When validate configuration, failover cluster validation report an error

At system configuration > Validate Active Directory Configuration

This is error message:

**Connectivity to a writable domain controller from node srv-12-01.clusterdomain.local could not be determined because of this error: Could not get domain controller name from machine srv-12-01.**

**Connectivity to a writable domain controller from node srv-12-02.clusterdomain.local could not be determined because of this error: Could not get domain controller name from machine srv-12-02.**

**Node(s) srv-12-01.clusterdomain.local srv-12-02.clusterdomain.local cannot reach a writable domain controller. Please check connectivity of these nodes to the domain controllers.**

I have 1 domain controller, 2 member server (joined domain and login with domain administrator user)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4025260/cluster-validation-test-fails-for-multi-site-cluster

More information

When you start a cluster validation test on a node, the node selects a domain controller to be used for the test. During the Active Directory configuration validation, all computers that are selected as part of the validation are pointed to use this domain controller. In a multi-site cluster scenario, the network communications may be designed in way where computers are only allowed to communicate with domain controllers that are in their local site. Therefore, these computers are prevented from communications with remote domain controllers. In this scenario, computers in other sites are not able to communicate with the selected domain controller which leads to the failure of the cluster validation test.

If the computers can communicate to a domain controller in the domain, and the domain controllers are successfully replicating, then the functionality of your failover cluster is not impacted.

In a multi-site cluster scenario, you can safely ignore the failed validation. Meanwhile, your failover cluster is still supported by Microsoft Technical Support.